# Module loading and unloading when calling createwindow

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to create a simple dropdown menu in a dialog box. Here is the bit of code that actually does it:

```
BOOL CALLBACK Remove(HWND hDlgc, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
//message handler for remove category box
{
    //UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);

    HINSTANCE current = GetModuleHandle(NULL);


    //GetModuleHandleExA(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_PIN, "comctl32.dll", NULL);

  CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOXW, _TEXT(""), CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 200, 200, hDlgc, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

This will work and it will show the combo box, but only after waiting for 2 minutes or so... very undesirable! my program will go into a not responding state before the combo box shows up. The output shows that comctl32.dll get loaded and unloaded about 1500 times before the combo box shows up. When it does, it is still unresponsive and I have to wait more until it begins to work. I tried pinning the module to stop the loading and unloading but that did not do anything. Any help appreciated. As you can see I am very new to win32 programming. I got the backend of my program to work nicely, its just this gui that is bugging me.

EDIT: here is the as short as i could get it code. Just create a blank desktop project in VS, and then replace the "about" function in the bottom with the following: (and also include commctrl.h)

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    HWND dd_Hand = CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOXW, _TEXT(""), CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE,
        20, 20, 200, 200, hDlg, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

If I do this, I get the symptoms described previously.

EDIT AGAIN: I put the createwindow function for the combobox into the WM_CREATE case of WndProc, and everything works as it should, loads instantly. I am starting to doubt that this is the right way to create a combobox within a dialog box. Any suggestions for doing this another way (havent been able to find a way to do this with a splitbutton resource) are also welcome.

Comment: Please condense your code to a small, self-contained example and post it.  No, it doesn't take 2 minutes/1500 loads to display a combo box with Win32.  THERE'S SOMETHING YOU'RE NOT SHOWING US.  An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is absolutely your next step.

Comment: Unrelated, changing a window style crashes your *computer* ? No offense, but what kinda of PoS are you running anyway, and how many hand grenade pins and meters of baling wire are being used to hold it together? Crash your *process* I can buy. the entire OS... you've got bigger problems.

Comment: @WhozCraig inspiron 5391... couple of years old but never had a program that would freeze the OS. I have the great achievement of making a program that does... haha.

Comment: @paulsm4 will do tomorrow.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you are setting the control ID of the combo box to 0. That's unlikely to be intentional, all the more since you aren't storing the window handle, making the control ID the only way for you to identify the control.

Comment: Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample? in view of the fact that COMBOBOX has been working for a long time. And [Dialog Box Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dialog-box-styles) cannot combine with [Combo Box Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/combo-box-styles).

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT I will do that right now. Do I use answer my own question to post the code, or should i start a new question?

Comment: @Vroom ZOOM: simply [Edit] your current question.  You don't need to start a new question.

Comment: You are creating a new combobox each time the dialog procedure is called. The dialog procedure is called a very large number of times, so you're creating a very large number of comboboxes. (About 1500 of them, given your other remarks.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Bingo! The devil was in the little details again. Thanks!

Comment: @VroomZOOM Would you answer yourself if nobody answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple. just put this code:

```
HWND dd_Hand = CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOXW, _TEXT(""), CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE,
        20, 20, 200, 200, hDlg, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

and the code that loads the combobox so it runs only once. No more problems. Also another even simpler way to do this would be to create a combobox resource and use the SendMessage() function.